# Form not validating when selecting option until clicking or tabbing out of select field with bootstrap/jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a form with two text inputs and a select field. I am using bootstrap with jQuery .validate plugin. I am able to perform standard form validation. However, my form does not immediately validate following selection. The text fields work fine, but my select field will not validate after I select. It only validates after I click or tab out of the field. How can I fix this?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="addressForm" name="addressForm">
  <legend>Search Your Property Here</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="streetAddress" class="control-label">Street Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="streetAddress" name="streetAddress" placeholder="Street Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="city" class="control-label">City</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="state" class="control-label">State</label>
      <select name="state" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" required="required"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected" hidden="hidden"></option> 
        <option value="AL">AL</option> 
        <option value="AK">AK</option> 
        <option value="AZ">AZ</option> 
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Search</button>
</form>
```

Here is my validation function:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#addressForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    streetAddress: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    city: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    state: {
                        required: true
                    },
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                },
                success: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                }
            });
        });
```

Here are my added scripts:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The code you posted* is working perfectly fine.  Click the button to trigger the messages.  As soon as you make a selection from the pull-down, the error message clears.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/zgw2s8a8/**

Even with BootStrap installed, I cannot reproduce your issue...

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/zgw2s8a8/3/**

---

However, I suspect that your particular problem (the one we cannot see) is being caused by the improper usage of the `success` callback in place of the `unhighlight` callback function.

```
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) { // <- do not use 'success' for this
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
}
```

**Updated DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/zgw2s8a8/2/**

---

The `success` callback is primarily used for manipulating the message label on valid elements, such as adding a green checkmark.  (Because, by default, the message label is hidden on valid elements).  Unfortunately, many of the online demos and tutorials show `success` being used where `unhighlight` would be much more appropriate.

If you're using the `highlight` callback function to override the default behavior, then you should also use the `unhighlight` callback function to perform the opposite actions.

To be more specific, your code only over-rides the built-in `highlight` function leaving the built-in `unhighlight` function in place... so the classes are not being added/removed exactly as designed.

---

Using the same file versions that you referenced in your latest edit, it's still working...

http://jsfiddle.net/zgw2s8a8/5/

Comment: Thank you for these recommendations. I have implemented them I am, however, still getting this bad functionality. I am updating my question with a screenshot

Comment: @BrianVanover, I don't need a screenshot as much as I need you to show the exact code that reproduces the issue.  As you can see in my demos, I'm using the code you posted and it's not showing that problem.

Comment: I believe its because I'm using jQuery 1.11. I was able to reproduce the error when I changed the version in jFiddle

Comment: Here is my solution with jQuery updated to 1.11 and it's working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/zgw2s8a8/4/

Comment: Thank you, this now works in Firefox which is what the spec requires. I was using the Google Chrome live demo from brackets and it wasn't working. Thanks for the help